# how to define a type under forEach in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I have an array of `PersonTypes` objects and would like to only use partial of key inside a forEach loop. what is more 
precise, correct coding in typescript to provide a type? I can do something like
`people.forEach((person: Pick<PersonTypes, 'name' | 'gender'>`
or
`people.forEach((person: PersonTypes) =>{`
or 
`people.forEach((person: any) =>{`
what is right way to code in typescript

```
export type PersonTypes = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  gender: boolean;
};
const people: PersonTypes[] = [
  {name: 'apl', value: 'apple', gender: true},
  {name: 'gal', value: 'google', gender: false},
]
people.forEach((person: Pick<PersonTypes, 'name' | 'gender'>) =>{
//people.forEach((person: PersonTypes) =>{
//people.forEach((person: any) =>{
  console.log(person.name);
  console.log(person.gender);
} )
```

Comment: What exactly does *"keep away me from roasting on PR"* mean? Why can't you just use the inferred type, `PersonTypes`, i.e. just write `.forEach(person => { ... });`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should just stick to:

```
people.forEach((person: PersonTypes) =>{


});
```

This is because each object within the `people` array is of type `PersonTypes`, and there is no actual need to extract properties away from the type.

In fact, there is no need to explicitly type person as `PersonTypes`, as people is of `PersonTypes[]`. TypeScript will automatically infer that each object within the array is `PersonTypes`, so this would be sufficient:

```
people.forEach((person) =>{


});
```

Alternatively, you may choose to destructure the parameter, which will make your function more concise and clean.

```
people.forEach(({ name, gender }) =>{  
  console.log(name);
  console.log(gender);
});
```

Comment: `Binding element 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type` I have error for destructure way

Comment: @jacobcan118 Show us how you destructure. Using `people.forEach(({ name, gender }) => ... );` works for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKwoGcIDsAqywWcAvHAN4BQccuAhgLbABccWMUAlrgOYDcNOADd6AGwCurdpx4ChvYLgAmmNgCMIEMcHq5BAX0EBjPBzgoIYHWwzY8hFFgDaAXTJxnQig2ZsA5PTW-gA0IuJSAUHWwKFwiipqCFBSBiHevtL+vOJxopJZvFq8OnEJqlBsAGbiWMBpVK5UljEAdFXQAKL0xgAWABT9FHRMwGHlmHAGAJRkAHyUQqa4ODqtYhC8-ZnTgrTLq8Drm-0TULtUM-xAA

Comment: @Terry i think the problem is on my customZip function which I cannt really change https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=4# how to solve it?

Comment: @jacobcan118 Please update your question instead: the playground link does not work btw

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzUgZxggFsAtTMACgDo6BDKKegTwIC44BBJ1gHnooWAPgCUAbwBQcOFGAwkUXI2ZtJAX0mhIsODBZhgcAArAoBHABUDwAnAC8cKTJT0SwTkSiYUAcwDc0nAAbvQANkgecF4+AUG+wCgAJmacAEYQEGHAgoHqgWg4RHCGEGDZDnAA2kF0NPhEpBTUVeKu7pwA5PTlnQA0IeGRXT3lwP1wCcmpelCR6n1BbW5Rnb7hE6ERq76ZvtkTUylQnAjhBMALALqikleSpWM0CNAAovRoABZUhuY4DsInEFfhYUM83h9vlRlu4BkczOpRPZhM4ZHgillgDQwhBfFR2sBRIE0eiUBZstjcVR4VAiUFEXkiUA. works for this one?

Comment: Hi, are you still facing the issue you have stated on your comment?

Comment: @jacobcan118 Please update your question: pasting the link in the comments is not helping others in the future, because the actual code has diverged too much from your original question (there is no mention of a custom zipping function)

Comment: When you destructure you can give it a type `forEach(([k, v]: [string, string]) => {`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional code you have provided, the `customZip` function is returning type of `any`, which of course causes issues later because the array will have a type of `any` instead of an inferred `PersonType[]`:

```
export function customZip(...arrays: Array<any>){
  return arrays
}
```

To fix this, it is as simple as using the concept of [generics in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables), which allows the compiler to infer the type of the array by itself:

```
export function customZip<T>(...arrays: Array<T>){
  return arrays
}
```

[See proof-of-concept example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzUgZxggFsAtTMAHgBUA+ACgDoWBDKKVgTwIC44Agh2606ASgDeAKDhwowGEii52nHlIC+U0JFhwYXMMDgAFYFAI4ah4ATgBeONNkpWJYPyJRMKAOYBuGTgAN1YAGyQPOC8fAKDfYBQAE3N+ACMICDDgVhRAjUC0HCI4IwgwbIc4AG0gliZ8IlIKMAZqiVd3fgByVgrugBoQ8MievorgQbgE5NT9KEiNAaCOtyju33Cp0Ij130zfbKmZlKh+BHCCYCWAXTEpG6kyiaYEaABRVjQACwYjCxwDjoTiC-0sKFeHy+vwYq3cQxO5g0YnsdGcsjwxSywCYYQgvgYnWAYkCGMxKEs2Vx+IYiKgJKCyPyDKAA).

You can choose to provide a type, or simply let TypeScript infer by itself. It doesn't really matter at this point: both will compile correctly:

```
// You let TypeScript do the inferring by itself
const people = [
  ...customZip([{name: 'apl', value: 'apple', gender: true},
  {name: 'gal', value: 'google', gender: false},])
];
```

...or...

```
// Your manually inform TypeScript what the type of an array member returned from customZip looks like
const people = [
  ...customZip<PersonTypes[]>([{name: 'apl', value: 'apple', gender: true},
  {name: 'gal', value: 'google', gender: false},])
];
```