# Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type error

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
    var allItems = await assetLoader.loadMore(); // returns (Folder[] & Project[])

    allItems.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item.getAssetId());
        console.log(item.getName());
    });
```

I get the following error `Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.` when running the code.

Can someone please help?

class AssetLoader {

Here's the class that assetLoader comes from:

```
export class AssetsDataLoader {
    allItems: Folder[] & Project[];

    public async loadMore() {
       return this.allItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to define a type under forEach in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209803/how-to-define-a-type-under-foreach-in-typescript)

Comment: That did not work

Comment: You have to type the parameter to the callback to array functions like `map` and `forEach`. Typescript (deliberately) will not infer the type for you, this was a deliberate decision Anders made. So make it `allItems.forEach((item: Folder & Project) => {` and it should work fine.

Comment: That's not the error I see in https://tsplay.dev/mZbeam, please give a [mre]. `Folder[] & Project[]` doesn't really make sense, you probably just want `(Folder & Project)[]`: https://tsplay.dev/NddzdN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change resolved type of loadMore to `Folder[] | Project[]`

Comment: I get the error TS2322: Type '(Folder | Project)[]' is not assignable to type 'Project[] | Folder[]'.   Type '(Folder | Project)[]' is not assignable to type 'Project[]'.     Type 'Folder | Project' is not assignable to type 'Project'.       Type 'Folder' is missing the following properties from type 'Project': _dcxComposite, getDCXComposite

Comment: I updated. Try now

Comment: Now I get the error TS2345: Argument of type 'Folder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Folder & Project'.   Type 'Folder' is missing the following properties from type 'Project': _dcxComposite, getDCXComposite. 

when I push to allItems

Comment: see My question again. I updated it.

Comment: Folder[] & Project[] is basically  any. It means to take all properties of Folder[] and Project[] and create a type that will have properties of both (from typescript perspective it does not make sense)

Comment: I think you need to provide me with information what allItems are  in practice. I mean example data. I will then try to decide which type will be sufficient here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240358/discussion-between-jkaczmarkiewicz-and-chris-hansen).